# Counting element's div's by using mocha testing framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, mocha.js

I have picked up an WebElement JSON objects by using xpath, this item is a div which has div's inside it.

```
it('Count terminals in view', function() {
    elems = browser.elements('/html/body/div[2]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]');
    console.log(elems.value);
});
```

The html code looks like this

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-pull-0 col-lg-pull-4">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div>Hardware Id</div>
                    <div ng-bind="terminal.hardwareId" style=" cursor: pointer; width: 100%" ng-click="downloadVM.openModal(terminal.hardwareId);" class="ng-binding">S8EVMOC00019</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div>Hardware Id</div>
                    <div ng-bind="terminal.hardwareId" style=" cursor: pointer; width: 100%" ng-click="downloadVM.openModal(terminal.hardwareId);" class="ng-binding">S8NOMOT00049</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div>
```

I need to be able to count the hardwareId's they are changeable, how can I loop properly through them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do the counting of the div's, just added an wild card "*" to the top div, and then looped through the count variable.

```
count = browser.elements('/html/body/div[2]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/*');
console.log(count);
for (el in count.value) {
    console.log(el); 
}
```